# Sending an environment variable to jetty using jettyRun in Gradle

Tags: jetty, gradle

How might I make an environment variable available to jetty using the gradle plugin? Some of the code it runs in a servlet requires a particular environment variable to be set, but I can't figure out a good way to send it to the jetty process like you can for a JavaExec task (via the `environment` method).

Also acceptable would be a property. For example, if I were to run some java, I'd include a `-Dproperty.name=blah` to send it the `property.name` property.

We can do it for Test and JavaExec tasks... can we do it for the JettyRun task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The container managed by the Jetty plugin runs in the Gradle process, so you need to set an environment variable or system property for that process.

The Jetty plugin is also quite outdated and limited, partly for exactly the reason that it runs inside the Gradle process. I recommend to instead give the [arquillian-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/aslakknutsen/arquillian-gradle-plugin) a try. We think that this plugin paves the way to better Gradle web container support.

Comment: You mean just `def environmentVar = 'blah'` or something?

Comment: Well, it works if I set the property in GRADLE_OPTS (via `GRADLE_OPTS="-Dproperty.name=blah"`), but I need something a *little* more deterministic than that. Is there a way to do it within a gradle script?

Comment: Sorry for the notification spam... adding a `doFirst { System.setProperty("property.name", "blah") }` to `jettyRun` worked.